# How add UITableView as a SubView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to add a UITableView as a subView in my current project. I'am new to Objective-C and I can't find a walkthrough on how to create a UITableView programmatically as a subview. Here's what I've done so far

In the AppDelegate.m

```
MJViewController *tableViewController = [[MJViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

In MJViewController.h

```
@interface MJViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

And in my MJViewController.m

```
@interface MJViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableViewCell *firstNameCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableViewCell *lastNameCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableViewCell *shareCell;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *firstNameText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *lastNameText;

@end

@implementation MJViewController

- (void)loadView
{
[super loadView];

// set the title
self.title = @"User Options";

// construct first name cell, section 0, row 0
self.firstNameCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
self.firstNameCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.5f];
self.firstNameText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.firstNameCell.contentView.bounds, 15, 0)];
self.firstNameText.placeholder = @"First Name";
[self.firstNameCell addSubview:self.firstNameText];

// construct last name cell, section 0, row 1
self.lastNameCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
self.lastNameCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.5f];
self.lastNameText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.lastNameCell.contentView.bounds, 15, 0)];
self.lastNameText.placeholder = @"Last Name";
[self.lastNameCell addSubview:self.lastNameText];

// construct share cell, section 1, row 00
self.shareCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
self.shareCell.textLabel.text = @"Share with Friends";
self.shareCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.5f];
self.shareCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}



// Return the number of sections
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 2;
}

// Return the number of rows for each section in your static table
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch(section)
{
    case 0:  return 2;  // section 0 has 2 rows
    case 1:  return 1;  // section 1 has 1 row
    default: return 0;
};
}

// Return the row for the corresponding section and row
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
switch(indexPath.section)
{
    case 0:
        switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0: return self.firstNameCell;  // section 0, row 0 is the first name
        case 1: return self.lastNameCell;   // section 0, row 1 is the last name
    }
    case 1:
        switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0: return self.shareCell;      // section 1, row 0 is the share option
    }
}
return nil;
}



// Customize the section headings for each section
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch(section)
{
    case 0: return @"Profile";
    case 1: return @"Social";
}
return nil;
}


// Configure the row selection code for any cells that you want to customize the row selection
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Handle social cell selection to toggle checkmark
if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {

    // deselect row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:false];

    // toggle check mark
    if(self.shareCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
        self.shareCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        self.shareCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
}

@end
```

How can I call the loidView in MJViewController inside a subView?

Comment: Where is your ViewDidLoad method?

Comment: It's in my other ViewController. And I want this UITableView to be loaded in that ViewController

Comment: You need subclass `MJViewController` from `UIViewController` and inside `loadView` init your tableView and add as a subview to view

Comment: @iSashok how can I add my tableView as a subview to my view inside the loadView?

Comment: something like this `self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
 self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
 self.tableView.delegate = self;
 self.tableView.dataSource = self;
 [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];`

Comment: @iSashok it's already working. Can you help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670452/how-to-display-an-image-and-two-labels-in-a-three-column-uitableview/37670634#37670634

Answer (score 0):

You can add table by following steps

1) Create object of MJViewController class

```
MJViewController *tableViewController = [[MJViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

2) add view of tableViewController to any UIView object you want to or you can add to viewcontroller's view to;

```
[self.view addSubview:tableViewController.view];
```

> you can not add **tableViewController** as subview directly as it is
>   viewcontroller type

Comment: What I am supposed to do with my AppDelegate? Cause when the program runs, the tableViewController is being displayed initially

Comment: remove this lines  MJViewController *tableViewController = [[MJViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];

but you have to set default viewcontroller for your app

Comment: I'm getting an "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" in the MJViewController *tableViewController = [[MJViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; should I put it inside the implementation of my other ViewController?

Comment: The "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" issue has been fixed. But my TableView is not showing on my view

Comment: check your table view by setting bg color or etc or make sure you have givein the correct frames for firstnamelabel