# How to display an image and two labels in a three column UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need to display multiple columns in my UITableView. The first column, will be an Image, and the next two will be a label. How can I do that programmatically?

For Example:

TableView

```
MyImage   Text#1     Text#2
Image     Another    Sample
```

Comment: You can say one tableview and add the three columns in tableview??

Comment: Yes one UITableView and three columns in it

Comment: You need use for it `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

You try with custom cell and then put a 3 views over there or taken directly UIImageView and Two UILabel. It is More easy.